# Logistic Regression - Guesstimating betas

Tags: logistic, sigmoid-curve

I am beginning an exploration on the topic, and was given the task of 'guesstimating betas 0 and 1' within 90% accuracy.
I tried many silly things, like using the data and then using google sheets to give me the linear regression equation of the data and assume that beta0 was the intercept and beta1 was the coefficient of such line.

I also was given a graph, and was estimating by the position of half the distance between the zeros and ones in relation to the x axis, calling it beta0 and then how steep the line is and call it beta1, to no success as well.
Can anyone point me to any direction at all?[image]

[guesstimating attempt](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QbCtZQSjxsxxBYu0rfx14b4sAlbQTzPPYMj2bejthGg/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Why "guesstimate" and not estimate the coefficients of a logistic regression?

Comment: That is how they phrased it. I would guess they do not want me to do any crazy calculation (which I do not know how to do), but eyeball it, but then again, they want 90% accuracy.

As a little bit of context, this comes from the EdX course Introduction to Data Science with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you seriously want a "guesstimate" of the coefficients for a logistic regression, here is one way.

There seems to be a very hard boundary around 39.  So I'm just going to guess that if age is greater than 39 then 1 else 0.

Here are my results when I do so

```
   yhat
y    0  1
  0 45  0
  1  0 55
```

I get 100% accuracy using this rule.  This is equivalent to setting the intercept in a logistic regression to 0 and using age - 39 as a predictor.

Why does this work?

A simple decision rule for logistic regression is to predict 1 when the probability is greater than 0.5 and 0 else (its not a good rule generally speaking, but its one you typically see in these intro courses).

The probability is modelled as a sigmoid curve

$$ P(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + \exp(-\beta_0 - \beta_1x)} $$

There is no need to actually calculate this.  $P(x)$ will be less than 0.5 whenever $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x < 0$.

Given that we can just predict "age > 39 then 1 else 0", how do we convert this to coefficients?  If we set $\beta_0 = 0$ and $\beta_1 = 1$ and let $x = age - 39$ then we basically get our decision rule.  $P(age - 39)$ will be less than 0 then age is less than 39, hence we will predict 0.  When age is greater than 39 then $P(age - 39)$ be greater than 0.5 and we will predict 1.

This answer relies on shifting age (i.e. doing age - 39). If $\beta_0 = -39$ and $\beta_1=1$ then we get the same behaviour without rescaling.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The automatic grader still says it is far off though...
I understand the 38.5, can you please elaborate the beta1?

Comment: I have no way of knowing what the grader wants.  If you are looking to get a correct answer, then I would suggest you: Show us what you've tried, and include more information from course

Comment: Hi, thanks again for giving me some inputs, all attempts I have done have been described in the beginning of the post, I do not have much else to go off from, except the graph and the data they shared with me.

They do have this tip:"Hint: It may help to focus on the age value that looks like the point of change in the plot. The logistic regression formula should result in a 0.5 probability with your guesstimated betas for that age value in order to achieve a good accuracy."

Comment: @AlvaroWang See my edited answer.  Clearly, there is some sort of hard cutoff at ~39, so try using a simple decision rule like "if age > 39 then 1 else 0"

Comment: Hi! May I ask you to elaborate by 'use decision rule'?
I will try to summarize my understanding from your inputs: beta zero should be around 39 due to the hard cut off, but I am left wondering about beta one

Comment: @AlvaroWang I've updated my answer to provide some more information on how I came up with the betas

Comment: I love you, Demetri. I have understood the process!